# Anybody know where this code to normalize spherical harmonics coefficients come from?

Tags: coefficients

I found this code on the internet and would like to know the theory behind it, can anybody point me in the right direction?

Here is the code:

```
 float4 SHCNormalize(in float4 res)
 {
    // extract direction
    float l = dot(res.gba, res.gba);
    res.gba /= max(0.05f, sqrt(l));
    res.r = 1.0;
    return res;
 }
```

To give you a little context, this code gets passed in 4 zonal harmonics coefficients representing a clamped cosine lobe in SH space.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the max in the function is to avoid devision by 0.0.  the res.r = 1.0f is an implementation detail that only applies to the code was looking at and has no theoretical basis.